# Basics about Nvidia GPU and graphics performance

Tags: drivers, nvidia, performance

Well, I'm new in this OS, and I already love it. Before I had Win7 but I'm not coming back.

I installed it yesterday in my laptop, a [HP Pavilion dv4-1528la](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?lc=es&dlc=es&cc=ar&product=4042921&) with a GPU [Nvidia GeForce 105M](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-g105m). Installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64, and so far everything is working properly.

But graphics are a bit slower (not so much, just minimum lags), so I went ahead and searched around and found that GPU drivers are not installed by Ubuntu since those are not open software. I went into my system settings, checked the "Additional Drivers" section, and it found 4 of them to be installed, all 4 of them Nvidia-related, although all of them seemed to be the same just different versions. I installed the first one (I guess the most recent one), and restarted, and the notification in the menu bar disappeared.

Now, I was expecting to find a section where to setup the graphics from a Nvidia manager or something (just like it was in W7, to improve performance and control display settings and all of that), that use to come with the driver, ¿am I right?... Well, I'm not able to find that section so I'm not sure if GPU is working or not.

In the forums I've been into, they talk about not installing drivers as standalone apps, or installing some other things like "bumblebee" to control Nvidia graphics, but since is my first time in Linux, I don't want to mess up something I don't know how to reverse later.

Any basic help step-by-step would be greatfully appreciated!

EDIT:
I've been checking extra in [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1165789) and all three commands work fine, so I *guess* now that GPU is installed and recognized and working properly, but I guess the question now is ¿how to enter to GPU settings to control display and graphics performance?